# OpenGL Translate Point With Mouse Drag

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm using the GLM library for OpenGL to render shapes relative to a camera using perspective and modelview matrices. The three camera vectors are as follows:

```
    glm::vec3 cam_pos(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f);       // e  | Position of camera
    glm::vec3 cam_look_at(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);   // d  | This is where the camera looks at
    glm::vec3 cam_up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);         // up | What orientation "up" is
```

The perspective and modelviews are generated via glm functions as follows:

```
    P = glm::perspective(fov, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    V = glm::lookAt(cam_pos, cam_look_at, cam_up);
```

I have implemented trackball camera movement to adjust the direction at which the camera is looking.

Now, I'm trying to code a draggable point object that follows the mouse movement according to which way the camera is looking. However, I'm having trouble with the math for doing this.

How would I get the translation matrix to translate the point with inside the GLFW mouse callback given the displacement of the mouse in x and y coordinates and the three camera vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Translate your 3 camera vectors to a **Rotation-Translation Matrix** (**RT**). With this **RT** matrix your can now linear transform any rigid object (basically anything in computer graphics) with respect to your camera location and pose.

Have a look at this http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Hope this approach helps.